# How To Quickly Convert UTC Time To Local Time in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timezone, datetime-conversion

Is there an easy way to convert the UTC time in this format (2020.05.28 15:45) into local time? I have a really long list to do the conversion.
For example, 2020.05.28 15:45 coverts into 2020.05.28 23:45; 2020.05.28 16:45 coverts into 2020.05.29 00:45. I don't know how to change the date in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/")+1/3`

Comment: I don't see how this was the acceptable answer. It doesn't even explain why!?

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for this and nothing mentioned in this page worked for me. So I later tried to make one which is much more easy and worked like a charm. Suppose the date is in D column.
=D2+TIME(6,0,0)

Here 6 is the hours, O is minute, 0 is second. Before doing this, please make sure the new column also converted to be Date and time similar to what you have in D column.

Comment: This IMO is the correct answer

Comment: Since a negative value can't be used within `TIME()`, you can subtract instead of add in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 1st value is in `A1`. Do/Put:

1. `=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,5))+DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,10),".","/"))+TIME(8,0,0)` in `B1`
2. r-click cell > format > custom : `yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm`
3. drag downwards.

Please share if it works/not/understandable. /(^_^)

Comment: This is correct, but it assumes the OP was asking to convert a text value to a datetime

Comment: yup... OP mentioned : "conversion" of "format" , not values.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(A1,5)+TIME(8,0,0),"yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm")
```

8 is the difference in between UTC and your GMT hours.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).